# Magento 2 force secure URL via XML?

Tags: magento2, xml, configuration, url

In M1 it was possible to add some lines to `config.xml` to force secure urls for certain pages ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <secure_url>
            <cms_newsletter>/newsletter</cms_newsletter>
            <sendfriend_product>/sendfriend/product</sendfriend_product>
        </secure_url>
    ...
```

What is the equivalent in Magento2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magento2 we can force secure URLs like this

`app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Url\SecurityInfo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="secureUrlList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout_index" xsi:type="string">/checkout</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

[reference](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/frontend/di.xml)